# Can I use Regex for this purpose?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I'm trying to validate an input field by making sure that only text, spaces and numbers can be inputted. I thought that the easiest way to do this would be using a Regular Expression by doing something like this:

```
function checkVal() {
var input = document.getElementById("input").value; 
if (input.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/) == null) {
    alert("error");
    }
}
```

More specifically I need to make sure that the underscore character isn't within this field (this is really important). From testing this it doesn't seem to be working properly but I think this is more so because I'm maybe using a regular expression for the wrong purpose and not because it's syntactically incorrect.

Would it just be easier for me to write a function to exclude the "underscore" character when typing in that input box?

EDIT: Just to make this a bit clearer, I only want to accept letter, numbers and spaces.

Comment: @sch sorry I should have been clearer, only want to accept letters, numbers and spaces, I will update the question to reflect this!

Comment: Personally, I would use `/.../.test(value)` instead of `value.match(/.../)`.  If your question is should I validate or try to block typing, then validate.  Typing is only one way of entering form field values.  At least with validation you can inform/remind them that underscores are not allowed (and _why_).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't forget to include the beginning of the string, `^` (and the space):

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use this regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/
```

The i is for incasesensitive:

EDIT:

```
/^[a-z0-9 ]+$/i
```

Comment: if you use the `i` modifier, `/^[a-z0-9 ]+$/i` is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your checking for the space, also you're only checking the string ends with numbers or charactors.

Try this:

```
function checkVal() {
var input = document.getElementById("input").value; 
if (input.match(/^[ a-zA-Z0-9]+$/) == null) {
    alert("error");
    }
}
```